# Nested forEach issue

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays of object, the first array (printers, around 80 elements) is made of the following type of objects:

```
[{
    printerBrand: 'Mutoh',
    printerModel: 'VJ 1204G',
    headsBrand: 'Epson',
    headType: '',
    compatibilty: [
      'EDX',
      'DT8',
      'DT8-Pro',
      'ECH',
    ],
    cartridges: [],
  },
   ....
]
```

The second array (cardridges, around 500 elements) is made of the following type of objects:

```
[
        {
            "customData": {
                "brand": {
                    "value": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "content": "ECH"
                    },
                    "key": "brand"
                },
                "printer": {
                    "value": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "content": "c4280"
                    },
                    "key": "printer"
                }
            },
            "name": "DT8 XLXL",
            "image": {
                "id": "zLaDHrgbarhFSnXAK",
                "url": "https://xxxxxxx.net/images/xxxxxx.jpg"
            },
            "brandId": "xxxxx",
            "companyId": "xxxx",
            "createdAt": "2018-03-26T14:39:47.326Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-04-09T14:31:38.169Z",
            "points": 60,
            "id": "dq2Zezwm4nHr8FhEN"
        },
  ...
]
```

What I want to do first is to is to iterate through the first array and and then iterate for all the cardridge available: if a the value customData.brand.value of a cardridge is included inside the array 'compatibility' of a printer, then I have to add this cardridge object inside the cardridges array of this printer. I have tried but somehow the iteration doesn't take place correctly. This is what I tried:

```
printers.forEach((printerItem) => {
      const printer = printerItem;
      printer.compatibilty.forEach((compatibilityItem) => {
        const compatibility = compatibilityItem;
        cardridges.forEach((cartridge) => {
          if (compatibility === cartridge.customData.brand.value.content) {
              printer.cartridges.push(cartridge);
            }

        });
      });
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Inside the `printer.compatibilty.forEach` there is no `cardridges`.

Comment: `cartridge.customData` does not contain a key `brand` ... so, I'd expect you're getting an error in the **developer** tools console. Are you?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - it's a separate array :p (I fell for that too)

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, now I see... well, not the best name choices I reckon.

Comment: I don't recommend to use arrow function when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing the wrong property. It should be `cartridge.customData.brandName.value.content`, carefully note `brandName.value` rather than `brand.value`

Comment: I changed into brand and the problem still persists

Comment: @Anto You've changed into "brand"? Do you mean you changed into "brandName"? Because changing into "brand" would be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're accessing it by the wrong property - `brand` and not `brandName`. 
Furthermore, if you're targeting everything but IE, you could simplify your nested for loops to utilize some fancy ES6 array methods.

```
printers.forEach((p) => {
  p.cartridges.push(cartridges.filter((c) => {
    const brandName = c.customData.brandName.value.content;
    return p.compatibilty.includes(brandName);
  }));
});
```

Comment: If you're going for ES6ishness, you would probably use `for.of`, rather than `forEach` as well...